# How is a specific person disappearing off of my hide from list with my status updates on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

There are about 5 people that I don't want seeing 99% of my status updates.  I clicked on the icon in my status box, chose custom, hide from and put the names in there.  Then I went to privacy settings (in the upper right corner of the home page), clicked "custom", hide from and put the names in there.  This has worked fine with no problems for 4 of them.  HOwever, 1 of them keeps disappearing from this list.  I know they are not able to access my account to change it (either through my computer left logged in or with my password). I DO know that they frequently deactivate their account, reactivate it, and fool with the spelling of their name.
I can't figure out how this 1 name keeps dropping off of my custom list but not the other 4.  Any idea???

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because he deactivates his profile. when someone deactivate his profile no one could see his name nowhere.